# Can't find Error (Project Euler #8 (Scala))

Tags: scala

So I've been doing the Project Euler questions in Scala but seem to be stuck on no 8 which asks to find the thirteen adjacent digits in a 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. The code I have written is as follows

```
import scala.io.Source

val digits1000File = "1000Digit.txt"
val lines = Source.fromFile(digits1000File).getLines.toList
val digits1000 = lines.mkString("")

//finds the greatest product of n adjacent digits in the string
def greatestAdjProduct(digits : String,n: Int): Int = {
  val xs = for(
    i <- 0 until digits.length - n
  ) yield digits.substring(i,i+n)
  xs.map(s =>s.map(_.asDigit).product).max
}

println(s"euler 8 = ${greatestAdjProduct(digits1000,13)}")
```

this works correctly for 4 digits but doesn't seem to work for 13. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: First of all, in your `for` comprehension, you should use `to` instead of `until` to avoid an off-by-one bug. You should also try to reduce your code to a [mcve] to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems.

First of all, in your `for` comprehension, you should use `to` instead of `until` to avoid an off-by-one bug. You can also replace said comprehension with `val xs = digits.sliding(n)`.

Second, you have an overflow error. The product of 13 digits is potentially too big to fit in an `Int`. The following returns -754810903 due to integer overflow:

```
"9999999999999".map(_.asDigit).product
```

To solve this, you can use `BigInt`:

```
"9999999999999".map(d => BigInt(d.asDigit)).product
```

`Long` also works here, but `BigInt` is a more general solution.